# projection map giving type arguments error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, mapping, expression

i am trying to use projection map to map the property values from source to destination as mentioned here in this question [Projection mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928757/using-linq-to-map-dynamically-or-construct-projections) looks like as below but getting error near select statement

> Error is : The type arguments for the method
> 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, Tresult>(IEnumerable,
> Func<Tsource, int, Tresult>)' cannot be inferred from usage.Try
> specifying type arguments explicitly

and below is the code sample

```
    public static IQueryable<TDest> ProjectionMap<TSource, TDest>(IQueryable<TSource> sourceModel)
where TDest : new()
    {
        var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);
        var destProperties = typeof(TDest).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite);
        var propertyMap = from d in destProperties
                          join s in sourceProperties on new { d.Name, d.PropertyType } equals new { s.Name, s.PropertyType }
                          select new { Source = s, Dest = d };
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "item");
        var memberBindings = propertyMap.Select(p => (MemberBinding)Expression.Bind(p.Dest, Expression.Property(itemParam, p.Source)));
        var newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(TDest));
        var memberInitExpression = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, memberBindings);
        var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDest>>(memberInitExpression, itemParam);
        return sourceModel.Select(projection);
    }
```

and then i am using above method below

```
    private static MechanicalData TransformMechanicalData(MechanicalData sourceMechanicalData, Dictionary<string, MasterSection> masterSectionMappedLibrary)
    {
        return new MechanicalData()
        {
            Acoustic = sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic
                       .Where(a => a != null)
                       .Select(ProjectionMap<LibraryAcoustic, LibraryAcoustic>(sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic.AsQueryable())).ToList() ?? new(),
        }
    }
```

Could any one please let me know where I am doing wrong, many thanks in advance.

Update:

```
Acoustic = sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic
                 .Where(a => a != null)
    .Select(acoustic => new LibraryAcoustic
    {
        Id = acoustic.Id,                
        IsApproved = true,                 
        NoiseCriteria = acoustic.NoiseCriteria,
        SourceOfData = acoustic.SourceOfData,
        SourceOfDataId = acoustic.SourceOfData.Id,
        MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library Acoustic"]
    }).ToList() ?? new(),
```

calling that transformMechanicalData method in below

```
   if (spaceTypeReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (spaceTypeReader.Read())
        {
            var id = spaceTypeReader.IsDBNull(0) ? default : Guid.Parse(spaceTypeReader.GetString(0));
            var mechanicalDataJson = spaceTypeReader.IsDBNull(1) ? "null" : spaceTypeReader.GetString(1);
            var srcMechanicalDataJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MechanicalData>(mechanicalDataJson);
            fixedSpaceTypesMechanicalData[id] = TransformMechanicalData(srcMechanicalDataJson, masterSectionMappedLibrary);
        }
    }
```

and mechanical data class be like

```
public class MechanicalData
{
    public List<LibraryAcoustic> Acoustic { get; set; }
    .........
}
```

Update 2:

model for libraryAcoustic

```
public class LibraryAcoustic 
{
    public double? NoiseCriteria { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SourceOfData")]
    public Guid? SourceOfDataId { get; set; }
    public virtual CodeStandardGuideline SourceOfData { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public MasterSection MasterSection { get; set; }
    public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

**FROM Model**

```
 "Acoustic": [
  {
        "Id": "d9254132-d11d-48dd-9b74-c0b60d1e4b8a",
        "IsApproved": null,
        "SourceOfData": {
            "Id": "c5bf3585-50b1-4894-8fad-0ac884343935",
            "CodeStandardGuidelineType": "GUIDELINE_OR_STANDARD"
        },
        "MasterSection": null,
        "SourceOfDataId": null,
        "NoiseCriteria": 1,
    }
],
```

**TO model:**

```
 "Acoustic": [
  {
        "Id": "d9254132-d11d-48dd-9b74-c0b60d1e4b8a",
        "IsApproved": true,
        "SourceOfData": {
            "Id": "c5bf3585-50b1-4894-8fad-0ac88434393",
            "CodeStandardGuidelineType": "GUIDELINE_OR_STANDARD"
        },
        "MasterSection": {Name:"test"},
        "SourceOfDataId": "c5bf3585-50b1-4894-8fad-0ac884343935",
        "NoiseCriteria": 1,
    }
],
```

Test Class update:

```
        SourceOfData sourceOfData = new SourceOfData()
        {
            Id = new Guid("c5bf3585-50b1-4894-8fad-0ac884343935"),
            Name = "test"
        };
        TestClassA170 testClassA170 = new TestClassA170()
        {
            Category = "test",
            SourceOfData = sourceOfData,
            SourceOfDataId = null,
            IsApproved = true,
            MinOutdoorAirACH = 1,
            MinTotalAirACH = 2,
            DirectExhaust = DirectExhaust.NO,
            PressureRelationship = PressureRelationship.NEGATIVE,
            RecirculatedAir = RecirculatedAir.NO,
            SpaceFunction = "10"       
        };
        List<TestClassA170> list = new List<TestClassA170>();
        list.Add(testClassA170);
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you are trying to invent Automapper with it's `ProjectTo`. Also there is already function to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334073/10646316

Comment: for this do i need to pass fields as comma separated strings

Comment: at the same time for two fields i need to set the values explicitly and not to map the values from source with your solution mentioned in that link, could you please suggest how to achieve this

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, could you please let me know how to apply the same and with those explicitly assigning fields and i will update the question to reflect the original code

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, i am getting an error here `sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic.Where(a => a != null).Select(BuildSelector<LibraryAcoustic, LibraryAcoustic>("id,SourceOfData.Id ")).ToList() ?? new(),` '`IEnumerable <LibraryAcoustic> does not contain definition for select ....`

Comment: Could you pleas point me in right direction where i am doing wrong that would be very grateful to me

Comment: You are far away from the right direction. When you applied AsQueryable to IEnumerable - first sign that you are doing something wrong. I can fix that but I do not see benefits from your code. Why just do not use Automapper?

Comment: I cannot use automapper here sorry

Comment: Any other libraries like LINQKit? Because here you need expression preprocessing.

Comment: Sorry I cannot use any third party library that is company policy

Comment: Maybe copy/paste small library part? ;) It will be best approach in your case.

Comment: Yeah sure that will be fine

Comment: here i am trying to set `IsApproved and mastersection` fields with other values not from source

Comment: For completing answer, you should update question with real query and how do you plan to use that. It is EF? Show real query in this case. It is just IEnumerable? Also sample is needed.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i am just serializing that into json and updating with raw sql

Comment: i will update the question and i am using this in EFcore migration

Comment: I have updated the question thanks

Comment: Well, probably you do not need third party libraries if you just work with IEnumeerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create mapping helper class which accespts additionally Dictionary as paraneter:

```cs
public static class PropertyMapper<TSource, TDest>
{
    private static Expression<Func<TSource Dictionary<string, MasterSection>, TDest>> _mappingExpression;
    private static Func<TSource, Dictionary<string, MasterSection>, TDest> _mapper;

    static PropertyMapper()
    {
        _mappingExpression = ProjectionMap();
        _mapper = _mappingExpression.Compile();
    }

    public static Func<TSource, Dictionary<string, MasterSection>, TDest> Mapper => _mapper;

    public static string MasterKeyFromClassName(string className)
    {
        // you have to do that yourself
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TSource, Dictionary<string, MasterSection>, TDest>> ProjectionMap()
    {
        var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);
        var destProperties = typeof(TDest).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite);
        var propertyMap = 
            from d in destProperties
            join s in sourceProperties on new { d.Name, d.PropertyType } equals new { s.Name, s.PropertyType }
            where d.Name != "MasterSection"
            select new { Source = s, Dest = d };
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "item");
        var dictParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dictionary<string, MasterSection>), "dict");
        var memberBindings = propertyMap.Select(p => (MemberBinding)Expression.Bind(p.Dest, Expression.Property(itemParam, p.Source))).ToList();

        var masterSectionProp = destProperties.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "MasterSection");
        if (masterSectionProp != null)
        {
            Expression<Func<Dictionary<string, MasterSection>, string, MasterSection>> dictRetrievalTemplate = (dict, value) => dict[value];
            var masterPropertyBind = Expression.Bind(masterSectionProp, ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(dictRetrievalTemplate, dictParam, Expression.Constant(MasterKeyFromClassName(typeof(TSource).Name)));
            memberBindings.Add(masterPropertyBind);
        }

        var sourceOfDataProp = destProperties.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "SourceOfDataId");
        if (sourceOfDataProp != null)
        {
            memberBindings.Add(Expression.Bind(sourceOfDataProp, Expression.Property(Expression.Property(itemParam, "SourceOfData"), "Id")));
        }

        var isApprovedProp = destProperties.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "IsApproved");
        if (isApprovedProp != null)
        {
            memberBindings.Add(Expression.Bind(isApprovedProp, Expression.Constant(true)));
        }

        var newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(TDest));
        var memberInitExpression = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, memberBindings);
        var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, Dictionary<string, MasterSection>, TDest>>(memberInitExpression, itemParam, dictParam);
        return projection;
    }  

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(exp);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
                .ToDictionary(i => (Expression) lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Then rewrite your function:

```cs
private static Expression<MechanicalData TransformMechanicalData(MechanicalData sourceMechanicalData, Dictionary<string, MasterSection> masterSectionMappedLibrary)
{
    return new MechanicalData()
    {
        Acoustic = sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic
                    .Where(a => a != null)
                    .Select(a => PropertyMapper<LibraryAcoustic, LibraryAcoustic>.Mapper(a, masterSectionMappedLibrary)).ToList(),
    }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to assign the two properties explicitly and how can i do that here for example `IsApproved and mastersection`. Isapproved i want to set always to true and mastersection is based on key passed to the dictionary and looking for nested properties as well. Here `SourceOfData` is nested inside `libraryAcoustic`

Comment: is there any way we can achieve with these conditions

Comment: Looks like I'm lost. Which properties? Post model FROM and model TO.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with conditions. Add parameters to `ProjectionMap` and use them when building ExpressionTree. For sure in this case you have to call `Compile` every time, so you have to invent new way how to cache such mappers.

Comment: if you see in question where i am doing with actual select mapping kind of here `Acoustic = sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic
                 .Where(a => a != null)
    .Select(acoustic => new LibraryAcoustic
    {
        Id = acoustic.Id,                
        IsApproved = true,   explicit setting
        NoiseCriteria = acoustic.NoiseCriteria,
        SourceOfData = acoustic.SourceOfData,
        SourceOfDataId = acoustic.SourceOfData.Id, // nested
        MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library Acoustic"] // updating explicitly
    }).ToList() ?? new(),`

Comment: No problem to call compile every time but how to pass these conditions, I believe this will work for nested properties as well

Comment: I do not see any conditions here.

Comment: the condition in the sense getting mastersection object from this dictionary key `MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library Acoustic"]`  and i am using same projectmap for other list objects as well in mechanical data class. We have other list objects same like as Acoustic. In that case the key for `masterSectionMappedLibrary` need to be passed based on source name

Comment: I will just update the FROM Model and ToModel in the question

Comment: Do not write,  Update1, Update2, just update question with new details. `MasterSection` property has the same name in each object?

Comment: not the same name its depends on the object name for example for `Library Acoustic` key  is `Library Acoustic` and for Enviroment list object the key is `Library Environment` like that it is. I updated from model and to model and `To model` what i am looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230983/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).

Comment: the key is always class name including space  like for example for this `LIbraryAcoustic`  key is `Library Acoustic` and for LibraryEnvironment` it is 'Library Environment`

Comment: some how it is setting wrong values for sourceOfDataId and isApproved properties

Comment: Still it is giving the same values any wrong in expression binding

Comment: Sorry I cannot mark as answer still I am getting wrong values set but thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry man, you have debugger, you see everything. Maybe there are properties which names are equals without case. This answer is doing exactly what you have requested - generates expression tree for mapping. For sure it needs tuning.

Comment: hmm, But properties are same with cases as well but i will look into one more time and why isApproved is setting false because of nullable properties

Comment: is there any way to ignore the case, i did checked both are same

Comment: `public bool? IsApproved { get; set; } ,         public Guid? SourceOfDataId { get; set; }`

Comment: could you please point me in direction where it needs tuning

Comment: Create class and apply mapper to this class. Check why mapper is not working. There is 20 lines of code which you can debug.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i will test and post the results here

Comment: I am trying to test through on plain object like this and what do i need to pass as first argument here i am looking to pass like as this `TestClassA170 arg1` but it is not taking  `var results = PropertyMapper<TestClassA170, TestClassA170>.Mapper(TestClassA170 arg1, masterSectionMappedLibrary);`

Comment: I have created testClass this time sourceOfdataId is correct but still isApproved is being false and i tried to setting to true and updated the question as well

Comment: it is looks like the value for IsApproved is null before and then with propertyMapper it is setting that to false and i tried initializing value with false in testClass and tried to set to true through property mapper and it worked.. I think with this it cannot set the values which we want if the SourceProperty is null and this is for bool

Comment: I can use third party library even with that same problem i beleive

Comment: Filter out IsApproved here `where d.Name != "MasterSection" && d.Name != "IsApproved"`

Comment: I did that one as well, the problem is i am trying to set "true" to nullable bool variable and if i try to set to true that is already having false value .. this way is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231047/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-svyatoslav-danyliv). i can use third party library as well

Comment: Oh man! I fixed isApproved assignment and the remaining is only one `sourceOfDataId` we should assign constant like this `var isApprovedPropertyBind = Expression.Bind(isApprovedProp, Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool?)));`  and not sure how to fix sourceOfDataId ... There should be something wrong with these assignments, Could you please let me know which library you referred to

Comment: because i am trying to assign source `SourceOfData.Id` to nullable Guid (i.e) `public Guid? SourceOfDataId { get; set; }`

Comment: Apply Expression.Convert(..., typeof(Guid?)) for part of assignment

Comment: sorry where exactly need to apply here in this line `Expression.Bind(sourceOfDataProp, Expression.Property(Expression.Property(itemParam, "SourceOfData"), "Id"));`

Comment: do you know where to apply conversion exactly

Comment: oh man! that worked and this is what i have used `Expression.Bind(sourceOfDataProp, Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(itemParam, "SourceOfData"), "Id"), typeof(Guid?)))`  and thanks for the support